# Run script in background using `&` or `()&`?

Tags: linux, bash, background-process, subshell

If I want to run a script in background, for example `a.sh`, should I run

```
./a.sh &
```

or should I put it in a subshell then background it?

```
(./a.sh) &
```

I test both and don't see difference, both works, can anyone tell me when should I use `()&` or just `&`? what's the real difference and cautious?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [putting subshell in background vs putting command in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286971/putting-subshell-in-background-vs-putting-command-in-background)

Comment: You should use the 1st. The 2nd just gives the spurious impression that it's doing something special, while in fact it isn't. Do not confuse it with `(./a.sh &)` which really is [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491157).